# Как закрыть форму из другой

Tags: c#, winforms

у меня в проекте 3 формы. Из первой формы открываю вторую а затем из второй третью(не закрывая формы), и после выполнения каких то операции на форме 3 пытаюсь закрыть третью и вторую форму. Как это сделать подскажите пожалуйста??? я все форумы в инете посмотрел, но ни один из методов не помог(((

Comment: А вы сами что пробовали то? Напишите хотя бы как пытались закрыть. Вообще форма - это класс, классы C# являются ссылочными типами, так что мешает передать ссылку в нужную форму на нужную форму и там ее закрыть?

Answer (score 1):

Это просто. Допустим, классы второй и третьей форм —  `Form2` и `Form3`. В классе `Form3` создаем отрытое поле для хранения ссылки на форму, которая ее открыла. Например, `Creator`.
В `Form2` открываем третью форму так:

```
    private void buttonOpen3dForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form3 = new Form3();
        form3.Creator = this;
        form3.Show();
    }
```

В классе `Form3` сначала закрываем 2-ю форму, а потом третью.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form Creator;

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }

    ...

    private void buttonClose2ndAnd3dForms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Creator.Close();
        this.Close();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Через поле не лучший вариант, ибо что будет, если мы забудем его указать? Если класс требует для работы другой класс, то стоит требовать этот класс при инициализации (конструктор).

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Согласен. Поле `Creator` сделаем `private`, а ссылку на вторую форму будем передавать в третью через параметр коструктрора `public Form3(Form myCreator) { InitializeComponent(); Creator = myCreator;}`